# Find if two elements from two different lists are found consequently in a string

Tags: python, string, list, data-preprocessing

I have a string like this one:

```
text = 'Your house is 2km away from school and 35dam away from the nearest hospital.'
```

And I have two lists like those ones:

```
numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']
measures = ['mm', 'cm', 'dm', 'm', 'dam', 'hm', 'km']
```

I want to **put a space between any possible number and any of the elements in the *measures* list** so that the output looks like the following:

```
output: Your house is 2 km away from school and 35 dam away from the nearest hospital.
```

Is there any way to separate any elements of two different list appearing together in a string?

Please, can you help me??

Comment: Welcome to SO! if [Barmar's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71864729/5730279) or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do this with a regular expression:

```
import re

measures = ['mm', 'cm', 'dm', 'm', 'dam', 'hm', 'km']
regex = re.compiler(rf'(\d)({'|'.join(measures)})\b')

output = regex.sub(r'\1 \2', text)
```

Explanation:

- `\d` matches a digit. `()` around it puts it in capture group 1.
- `'|'.join(measures)` creates alternatives like `mm|cm|dm|m|dam|hm|km`. `()` around it puts this in capture group 2.
- `\b` matches a word boundary

In the replacement string, `\1` and `\2` get the values from the capture groups. The space between them adds the desired space.